# Tabulizing data off website PDFs (w/ various formats) assigning each event values according to HTML link titles

Tags: html, r, pdf, extract, tabular

I've been trying to automate the process of manually typing down the data from the ATF's trace data site (see "URL") but it's been a fairly big pain as I've only been able to collect the each URL link that holds the PDFs and assign it to its correct State/Territory and Year. The newer files 2017-2019 have data "tables that are relatively easier to pull data from compared to 2014-2016, e.g. I'm referring to page 10 of the [Trace Data report 2019](https://www.atf.gov/file/146951/download) and [Trace Data report 2014](https://www.atf.gov/file/89621/download).

It's the latter that I'm having trouble with the most as the data is not stored in something that looks like a table but surrounding a (!)pie-chart. There have been some promising R packages such as "pdftools" and "tesseract". But I'm very much an amateur when it comes to trouble-shooting advanced analytical packages such as these.

It's my guess that I'm still a ways off from where I want to be with the final product as I would need to mine the bottom text of page 10 to find how many "other" weapons were traced to a city, as well the number of weapons where a recovery city couldn't be determined. But if anyone has any suggestions on what I could try next or to even make the working code more efficient, I'd appreciate it.

```
URL <- "https://www.atf.gov/resource-center/data-statistics"

  html <- paste(readLines(URL))
  library(xml2)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(rvest)
  library(stringr)
  x <- c('\t\t\t<div><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></div>','\t\t</tr><tr><td><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></td>','\t\t\t<td><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></td>')
  r <- read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes("a") %>%  map_df(~{
    Link <- .x %>% html_attr("href")
    Title <- .x %>% html_text()
    data_frame(Link, Title)
  }) %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl('node',Link, fixed = T))
  
  r <- as.data.frame(r)
  x <- c('<ul><li><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></li>','\t<li><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></li>')
  states <- c('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','District of Columbia','Florida','Georgia','Guam & Northern Mariana Islands','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania','Puerto Rico','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming')
  s <- list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(r)){
    s[[i]] <- read_html(r$Link[i]) %>% html_nodes("a") %>% map_df(~{
      Link <- .x %>% html_attr("href")
      Title <- .x %>% html_text()
      data_frame(Link, Title)
    }) %>% mutate(Year <- r$Title[i]) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(Title %in% states | str_detect(Title, "Virgin Islands")) %>%
      dplyr::filter(grepl('download',Link, fixed = T))
    trace_list = do.call(rbind, s)
  }
  names(trace_list)[3] <- "Year"
```

Progress so far...

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_file <- "https://www.atf.gov/file/146951/download"
text <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
cat(text[10])
vtext <- as.list(str_split(text[10],"\n"))
x <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(vtext), nrow=length(vtext), byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x1 <- pivot_longer(x, cols = 1:length(x),names_to="X1",values_to="X2")
x1$X2 <- trimws(x1$X2)
x1 <- x1[c(8,12),]
x1[1,2] <- sub(" ","_",x1[1,2],fixed=T)
library(splitstackshape)
x1 <- as.data.frame(cSplit(x1, 'X2', sep=" ", type.convert=FALSE))
x1 <- x1[,c(2:length(x1))]
colnames(x1) <- x1[1,]
x1 <- x1[-1, ] 
x2 <- pivot_longer(x1, cols = 1:length(x1),names_to="city",values_to="count")
```

mixing both pdftools amd tesseract...

```
library(tesseract)
img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert("https://www.atf.gov/file/89621/download", format = 'tiff',  dpi = 400)
text <- ocr(img_file)
strsplit(text[10],"\n")
```

Expected output:

| year | state | city | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | AL | Birmingham | 100 |
| 2018 | CA | Los Angeles | 200 |
| 2017 | CA | None | 30 |
| 2017 | CA | Other | 400 |